# Run shell script in coldfusion cfm page

Tags: coldfusion

I like to run shell script (e.g abc.sh) through cfm page in coldfusion and it will work like      ./abc.sh

```
 <form method="post" action="#request.myself#migrate.mup" 
    name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="FileContents" type="file" value"get file">
    </br></br></br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File"> 
</form>

<cfif isDefined("Form.FileContents") >
<!--- If TRUE, upload the file. --->
<cffile action = "upload" 
    fileField = "FileContents" 
    destination = "../../../../Tests/migration/" 
 mode = "775"
    accept = "text/xml" 
    > Done......File Uploaded


<CFEXECUTE
NAME="/abc.sh"
TIMEOUT="999">
</CFEXECUTE>
```

and my abc.sh file is

```
#!/bin/sh
#insert data
./lq.sh data.xml migrate
```

I like to execute abc.sh (os is linux)

Comment: Great. Let us know how it goes. Although, these kind of statements are better suited for Twitter. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, where people ask for help with their code.

Comment: i did update my question please review it

Comment: A bit better, but you still haven't explained what the **problem** is you are facing.

Comment: Does abc.sh function properly when you run it outside ColdFusion?

Comment: problem is that CFEXECUTE dose not execute the file in linux it open the file and start reads ./lq.sh and gives error. My ./abc.sh should update database using liquibase in linux enviornment

Comment: Good to see a CFML question closed by five twonks who wouldn't know CF if it bit them on the butt. Possibly leave this sort of thing to people who *do* understand the question, eh? Voting to reopen so less socially inadequate people can actually answer it.

Comment: The name attribute actually takes the absolut path to the program to execute. U sure, it lies in the root?

Comment: yes abc works fine in linux ./abc.sh

Comment: yes abc works fine in linux ./abc.sh  but it is not in the root it is one dir up to the webserver dir there we have some test data and properties file for database connection, liquibase files what i want is that in my coldfusion web application a button will upload file (data.xml) which is (liquibdase format with changeset) xml. and from cfm page when data.xml upload it will execute the abc.sh  Now i have to go through putty to execute abc.sh there i have to write ./abc.sh and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, you write ./abc.sh to execute in current folder. That what's the dot means. Your cfexecute tag does not have a dot in the name attribute

Comment: yes you are write. but the problem is that cfexecute start reads that file and give me ( error line 3  can't find ./lq.sh ) if i write in my abc.sh on line 3 sh lq.sh it goes to lq.sh which is in the same dir and start read lq.sh . what i like to do it will work like in linux sh abc.sh

Comment: Are the ColdFusion user and the .sh user the same or in the same group? This might be a permissions error.

Comment: They are same no permission problem. I must say sorry to you because i think cfexecute didn't work out side the current dir it looks like it is working in the same dir although i didn't able to get the result but start getting error like liquibsae and oracle drivers path. i think i have to give full path in that file to connect database. thanks for helping me out.